# How to access SQLite db, created in an Activity, from a Fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I have a local SQLite db created in FormActivity.java, like so:

```
db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

String name = user.getString("name");
String surname = user.getString("surname");
String title= user.getString("title");

db.addUser(name, surname, title);
```

I then have a Fragment with several textFields. I wish to fill these fields with the data from the db I created in the activity. As below:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        //set inputs for fields
        inputTitle = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        inputName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.foreText);
        inputSurname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.surnameText);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

        return v;

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String surname = user.get("surname");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        inputName.setText(name);
        inputSurname.setText(surname);
        inputTitle.setText(title);
    }
```

My problem at the moment is db.getUserDetails(), I don't know and cannot find how I can access the db from within the fragment.
I'm sure it's a simple fix but could someone set me right here please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this method

```
 HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
```

before return your View and create `SQLiteHandler` in `Fragment`

```
 db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
```

Final code will be.

```
    // Fetching user details from sqlite
 HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

 String name = user.get("name");
 String surname = user.get("surname");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
 inputName.setText(name);
 inputSurname.setText(surname);
 inputTitle.setText(title);

 return v;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create `Object` of `SQLiteHandler` in `Fragment`

```
db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
```